# Значення фрази "замаїлися камінці у нирках" у пісні "Друзі" гурту "Діти інженерів"

Tags: значення-слів

Не можу зрозуміти значення фрази "замаїлися камінці у нирках" у пісні "[Друзі](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvPYuhhHds0)" гурту "Діти інженерів":

> **Замаїлися камінці у нирках**
> Кидаємося враз на всі фронти
> Гучно сміємося, моїм друзям в розвідку не йти, не йти

Згідно з словником, [замаювати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) це

> ЗАМА́ЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., ЗАМАЇ́ТИ, аю́, аї́ш і рідко ЗАМА́ЯТИ, а́ю, а́єш, док., перех. Прикрашати зеленню, квітами, гілками і т. ін. Просить він [Марець] в сонечка помочі з неба — Буйнесенькі стануть теж у пригоді — Землю сушити, травицею вкрити, Первоцвітом, рястом гай замаїти (Коцюб., І, 1955, 427); * Образно. Місяць виписав.. на їй [стіні ] нове срібно-синяве вікно, замаявши його рясно густими., кучерявими од грат тінями, мов галуззям винограду (Вас., II, 1959, 59).

Це дійсно те значення, яке використане у пісні? Камені у нирках **прикрасились**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, майже так, як ви кажете, лиш заплутаніше й метафоричніше.

Декілька уточнень:

1. ЛЮДМИЛА ПІДКУЙМУХА. БАТЯРСЬКИЙ ЖАРГОН ЯК СПЕЦИФІЧНИЙ СОЦІОЛЕКТ ЛЬВОВА

> Назви процесів пиття алкоголю позначали такими лексемами: жльопати ‘пити алкоголь’, заливатися в дрібний мак ‘пити до безтями, банячити’, закропитися ‘випити надмір алкоголю’, **замаїтися** ‘випити надмір алкоголю’

Думаю, необов'язково пояснювати, що нирки й алкоголь пов'язані.

Отже, разом із вашим джерелом, на мою думку, найкраще пояснення таке:

Ліричні герої люблять "випити надмір алкоголю", після чого виблискують камінці у їхніх нирках. Ставляться вони до себе несерйозно, на що вказує "в розвідку не йти". Тому й каміння в нирках сприймають не як проблему, а як явлення краси (маємо справу з навмисним абсурдизмом. каміння в нирках — серйозна проблем. а тут сприймається як красиві камінчики). І думаю, що не камені прикрасились, а радше камені прикрашають, виблискують, як можуть прикрашати дорогоцінні камені.