# Яка етимологія у слова "замаювати"?

Tags: етимологія, історія-мови

> **Замаїлися** камінці у нирках
> Кидаємося враз на всі фронти
> Гучно сміємося, моїм друзям в розвідку не йти, не йти

Додав це слово, **замаювати**, до словника [Анки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki) і вивчив, але хочеться знати, звідки воно сталося, щоб краще запам'ятати. Звик додавати етимологію до словничка.

Не можу знайти у словнику [Горох](https://goroh.pp.ua/) - можливо, проводжу пошук по неправильному корню слова

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Значення фрази "замаїлися камінці у нирках" у пісні "Друзі" гурту "Діти інженерів"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%86%d1%96-%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%96%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%94%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%96-%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%94%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%96)

Comment: It looks you have asked this (or similar) question before… :)

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine - ні, я хочу тепер дізнатися етимологію, походження слова ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В більшостї випадків для пошуку етѵмолоґії певного слова достатньо обрїзати слово. Ось ві вашому запитаннї [Значення фрази *замаїлися камінці у нирках* у пісні *Друзі* гурту *Діти інженерів*](/a/7199/585) згадані декілька словникових форм: *замаювати*, *замаїти* і *замаяти*. Що ж, вони справдї не знаходяться, тоді прибираїмо приросток *за-*, але бажано перед цим перевірити, що це справдї приросток, що зазвичай легко перевіряїться тим ж тлумачним словником, наприклад Горох знаходить лише *маїти*:

> [МАЇ́ТИ](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%97%D1%82%D0%B8) маю́, маї́ш, *недоконаний вид*, *кого*, *що*, *діалектизм*. Заквітчувати.

Там ж вже показуїть ся і етѵмолоґія:

> [МАЙ](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%97%D1%82%D0%B8#11375) «клечання, зелень, якою прикрашають хати на зелені свята»
>
> - припускається також зв’язок з назвою місяця *май* «травень» (Brückner 317 – 318);
> - розглядається як утворення від кореня **ma* «хитатися, коливатися» в словах *ма́яти*, *маха́ти* (Горяев 200);
> - не зовсім ясне;
>
> р. [*май*] «клечання», бр. [*май*] «зелень, якою прикрашають хати на зелені свята», п. maj «тс.», ч. máj(e) «ритуальне дерево, прикрашене квітами і стрічками», слц. máj «дерево, що ставиться перед вікном коханої», нл. maja «весняна берізка», схв. *мȃј*, *мȁј* «весняна квітка; зелень», слн. máj «ритуальне дерево, прикрашене квітами і стрічками»;
>
> *маї́ня* «клечання, зелень, якою квітчають хату на зелені свята; знаки в полі з гілок»; *маї́ти* «заквітчувати зеленню»; *майина́* «тс.; опудало»; *майи́ти* «робити з гілок знаки в полі»; *ма́йка* «букет на щойно поставленому зрубі хати; віха (знак)»; *майни́й* «укритий листям»; *майова́т* «гуляти»; *маюва́ти* «вкриватися листям»; *обма́ювати* «прикрашати зеленню»; *розмай*.

Тут є в списку *маювати*, але воно не знаходить ся скорїш за всього через технічні проблеми, а саме через знак наголосу. Якщо знаїте як додавати [наголос](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%97%8C%CC%81) і де він, то можна пробувати шукати по Горосї, але через [Ґуґл](//google.com.ua/search?q=site:goroh.pp.ua+%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F+%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%CC%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22&lr=-lang_ru), що, так, менш зручнїше.

Цїкаво, що тут не згадані *розмаїтий*, *розмаїття* ітп, котрі наче близькі по духу [дещо субєктівно, так] і відоміші загалу — через частовживаність теж [бо наприклад *маїти* справдї дуже рїдке слово]. Хоч це слово розглядають окремо, гадаю, воно і можить допомогти запамятати. Там етѵмолоґія теж не дуже однозначна і теж є думка щодо звязку до [*махати*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8#11905), котре вже маїть визначенїшу етѵмолоґію — від індоевропейського **mā* «махати», і для цїкавого факту: популарне анґлійське слово *meme* є далеким коґнатом, котре походить від  ґрецького *μίμος* «фокусник; фокус; наслідування», що згадане в етѵмолоґічному словнику.

> [РОЗМАЇ́ТИЙ](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%97%D1%82%D0%B0#14673) «різноманітний»
>
> - загальноприйнятої етимології не має;
> - виводилось (Brückner 465) від основи *maj-ati* «махати» (пор. укр. *розма́й* «щось таке, що розвівається»);
> - непереконливо зіставляється (Machek ESJČ 520) з ч. zamanouti si «задумати, заманутися»;
>
> п. rozmaity, ч. rozmanitý, [rozmaity], слц. [rozmajitý], rozmanitý;
>
> *розмаїте́ний*; *розмаї́тити*; *розмаї́ті* «у різний спосіб»; *розмаї́тний* «тс.»

Comment: У Фасмера на корінь "маїти" ("маять") дається значення "тортурувати, втомлювати".
> ORIGIN: Родственно д.-в.-н. muоеn "трудиться, стараться", ср.-в.-н. müen, muowen, д.-в.-н. muohî ж. "труд", гот. afmauiþs "утомленный", д.-в.-н. muodi "усталый", греч. μῶλος "тягота, труд", μώλυς "ослабевший, исчерпанный, тупой", лат. mōlēs "тяжесть, масса"

Comment: Перепрошую, та що значить «обрізати слово»?

Comment: @Skill залишити лише [корїнь](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Корінь_(мовознавство)) \[не плутати з [основою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Основа_слова)]. Там згодом вже описано процес: _тоді прибираїмо приросток за-_.